# $project , $match returns values and then group by returns null in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb. I want to total for given week of year. I have used aggregate function in which I have used $project then $match then $group. It returns null value. But When I use aggregate function with $project and $match only. In that case it returns documents.

```
filteredOrders = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        day: { $dayOfWeek: '$createdAt' },
        week: { $week: '$createdAt' },
        month: { $month: '$createdAt' },
        year: { $year: '$createdAt' },
        total: '$totalPrice',
      },
    },
    { $match: { week: 10, year: 2021 } },])
```

The above code returns documents.
But

```
filteredOrders = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        day: { $dayOfWeek: '$createdAt' },
        week: { $week: '$createdAt' },
        month: { $month: '$createdAt' },
        year: { $year: '$createdAt' },
        total: '$totalPrice',
      },
    },
    { $match: { week: 9, year: 2021 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          createdAtDay: { $dayOfWeek: '$createdAt' },
          createdAtWeek: { $week: '$createdAt' },
          createdAtMonth: { $month: '$createdAt' },
          createdAtYear: { $year: '$createdAt' },
        },
        count: { $sum: '$totalPrice' },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

The above code returns null for all elements in _id and returns 0 in count.
Please help me...

Comment: you have already projected values to new field names, need to use new field names for `group`

Comment: But I have tried that one . But that gives an error "variable is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use newly projected field from previous stage for the next `$group` stage

```
filteredOrders = await Order.aggregate([
{
  $project: {
    day: { $dayOfWeek: '$createdAt' },
    week: { $week: '$createdAt' },
    month: { $month: '$createdAt' },
    year: { $year: '$createdAt' },
    total: '$totalPrice',
  },
},
{ $match: { week: 9, year: 2021 } },
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      createdAtDay: '$day',
      createdAtWeek: '$week',
      createdAtMonth: '$month',
      createdAtYear: '$year',
    },
    count: { $sum: '$total' },
  },
},
```

]);

Comment: yea. I tried . But stackoverflow says You can accept it as answer in 1 min